# How to create a dynamic form in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, dynamic

On a WordPress website I would like to have a form where users can submit data about courses they are offering, but some offer more and different courses than others. Therefor, I would like to give them an option to add another field to the form, so it would look a bit like the following.
The basic form would look like this:

```
Course name (text field) - language (dropdown) - date (date picker or text field)
```

But if a user offers 2 courses, they would be able to press a button like 'add row' and it would give them the same row of three fields again. Looking like

```
Course name 1 - language - date [add row]
Course name 2 - language - date [add row]
```

But also, if a user offers 1 course, but in 2 languages and on 3 dates, they should be able to enter that, looking like

```
Course 1 - language 1 [add language]- date 1[add date][add row]
           language 2 [add language]- date 2[add date][add row]
                                      date 3[add date][add row]
Course 2 - language 1 [add language]- date 1[add date][add row]
           language 2 [add language]- date 2[add date][add row]
           language 3 [add language]
```

And so on and so forth...

Would it be possible to do this with dynamic fields and how? Is there a WordPress plugin that already offers this (preferred)?

Comment: not being rude but you need to attempt this yourself before asking. Q's asking for plugin recommendations are off topic and google will answer that for you anyway. As a minimum you need to learn how to add a custom page template, create your form in html and then javascript to respond to the user. Or just hire someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to do that on the front end.

For that you would need some jquery.

Group the fields about the course into a row. For example:

```js
$('#add-row').click(function(){

  $('.rows').append("<div class='course-row'><input type='text' name='course-name'><input type='text' name='language'><button class='remove'>remove</button></div>");
  
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){

  $(this).closest('.course-row').remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='rows'>
  
  <div class='course-row'>
    <input type='text' name='course-name'>
    <input type='text' name='language'>
    <button class='remove'>remove</button>
  </div>
  
</div>

<button id='add-row'>Add row</button>
```

So instead of the second input you can use select and wrap all of that into a form. Then once the form is submitted just fetch and parse incoming data from repeated fields as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). It is a WordPress plugin to assist in form creation and has a [repeater field addon](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/), which will help you.

The repeater fields allows you to group inputs together and let's the user repeat those as necessary. Check out [their doc on nested repeaters](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/) to achieve what you want.